# Python Selenium TypeError: WebDriver.get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, automation

Whenever I run my code I get the error:
`TypeError: WebDriver.get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from getpass import getpass
    
email = getpass("hi")

driver = webdriver.Edge()
    
edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")

driver.get('https://bing.com')
driver.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=19&id=264960&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsecure%2fPassport.aspx%3fedge_suppress_profile_switch%3d1%26requrl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252f%253ftoWww%253d1%2526redig%253dAA7AA39B92914967ABF4C49E48D533D1%2526wlexpsignin%253d1%26sig%3d2941CEB8036F6DC8052EDD44026F6C8B%26nopa%3d2&wp=MBI_SSL&lc=2057&CSRFToken=a477312e-86ba-4e35-8882-405e7286e285&cobrandid=c333cba8-c15c-4458-b082-7c8ce81bee85&aadredir=1&nopa=2')
driver.get(By.XPATH,('//*[@id="i0116"]') ).send_keys(email)
```

I've tried adding an extra set of parenthesis "()" where the xpath text is but it didn't work. The answer I found was from seven years ago so I don't think it's relevant anymore.
I was expecting the code to enter the text "hi" into the input field.